# Generate code during automatic build in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, code-generation, annotation-processing

I am writing a code generator that generates additional classes for each class annotated with a certain annotation. I have other classes in my project that has to refer these generated classes. If I can somehow integrate my code generator into the automatic build process, then I figure the generated code will always stay up to date.

Is this possible? Can I do this if write a new custom builder?

**EDIT (2/7):** 
I looked at Lombok which is doing something similar. However, it modifies the AST from an annotation processor by using undocumented internal methods in eclipse. I don't want to take that risk. Moreover, I think they never wanted to do source generation - just byte code generation.

Comment: https://projectlombok.org/ Adds similar functionality to Java and eclipse, so it may be worth looking how it is done there.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have annotation processing configured, you can use the annotation processing plugin for m2e.
Here's the marketplace link: https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/m2e-apt